# MVC: cookies are not persisting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an overlay div inside a condition. If `Cookies["User"]` is null then I show an overlay div having two radio buttons and a submit button.

When user selects `radio` option and clicks submit button, when by ajax call,
I am calling an action which sets cookies.

I have put the overlay div inside *_Layout* page, so for every call it checks for session.

My issue is: First time after setting cookies, it's not persisted for second time.
Below is my method which sets cookies:

```
 public ActionResult SaveUserTypeCookies(string usertype, string returnUrl)
     {
        if (Request.Cookies["User"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["User"];
            cookie.Values["UserType"] = usertype;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("User");
            cookie.Values["UserType"] = usertype;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
     }
```

Below is my condition for overlay div:

```
 @if ((Request.Cookies["User"]== null))
 {
     <div id="overlay_div" class="overlay"></div>
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax to get cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("User");
```

And check if cookie exists use this in C#:

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["User"] != null
```

And to create and save cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("User");
cookie.Values["UserType"] = usertype;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.MaxValue;
HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```